# Print date from input ID user in java

Tags: java, date, java-17

I  have to make a code that  take an user name input and then  an ID number  that is  based format as   ( 1102199344556699 - where the first 8 characters is his day of birth).
My code:

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //user input
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        int length = scanner.nextLine()
                .length();
        System.out.println(length);

        //user id input
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your id number");
        String idNUmber = scanner2.nextLine();
        if (idNUmber.length() < 11) {
            throw new InvlaidIdException("invalid");
        } else {
        String dateOfBirth = idNUmber.substring(0, 8);

    //found this way,on the output is giving me from input -110219935656525
   //output is ok but as you can see on My output i get some extra things (please see OUTPUT)
        TemporalAccessor date = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyy").withLocale(Locale.FRANCE).parse(dateOfBirth);
            System.out.println(date);
                }
            }
        }
```

INPUT user Id -`110219935656525`

OUTPUT:

```
This is  the birthday date: {},ISO resolved to 1993-02-11
```

How can i get rid of  {},ISO resolved to ?
Thanks,

Comment: You want to use `LocalDate`, not `TemporalAccessor`. Simply `LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateOfBirth, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyy", Locale.FRANCE));`. As an aside, reuse the same `Scanner`, don’t create a second one.

Comment: Thank you verry much for your contribution . I will also give it a try with what you explain  

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more resarches
I got the output i needed :)

Here is the full code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //user input
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        int length = scanner.nextLine()
                .length();
        System.out.println(length);

        //id user input
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String civilIdStr = "";
        System.out.println("Enter your id number");
        civilIdStr = input.nextLine();
        if (civilIdStr.length() < 11) {
            throw new InvlaidIdException("invalid");
        } else {
// sout the date from the Id user input  (format DD-MM-YY)
                String dob = civilIdStr.substring(0, 8);
                System.out.println("Date of birth from user ID: " +
                        dob.substring(0, 2) + "/" +   //DATE
                        dob.substring(2, 4) + "/" +   //MONTH
                        dob.substring(6, 8));         //YEAR
            }
        }
    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter your name: 
Victor
6
Enter your id number
11021993554644
Date of birth from user ID: 11/02/93
```